# Commit checks not working in PyCharm on macOS

Tags: pycharm, commit

The issue is happening on macOS Monterey `12.6.5` and PyCharm `Build #PY-231.8109.197`. Whenever I try selecting any of the commit checks found in `settings > version control > commit`, nothing gets selected and the apply button stays disabled.

[image: checks]

I tried restarting, and deleting `.idea`. Neither is working.